# I am having trouble getting the correct results using XML EXPLICIT in T-SQL (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am getting strange results from a query using XML EXPLICIT mode in T-SQL (SQL Server 2008).

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Here is my example:

```
declare @parents table(id int, connection int, title nvarchar(255));
declare @children table(id int, connection int, title nvarchar(255));

insert into @parents(id, connection, title)
values(1, 21, '1');
insert into @parents(id, connection, title)
values(2, 22, '2');
insert into @parents(id, connection, title)
values(3, 23, '3');
insert into @parents(id, connection, title)
values(4, 24, '4');
insert into @parents(id, connection, title)
values(5, 25, '5');
insert into @parents(id, connection, title)
values(6, 26, '6');

insert into @children(id, connection, title)
values(1, 21, '1a');
insert into @children(id, connection, title)
values(2, 22, '2a');
insert into @children(id, connection, title)
values(3, 23, '3a');
insert into @children(id, connection, title)
values(4, 24, '4a');
insert into @children(id, connection, title)
values(5, 25, '5a');
insert into @children(id, connection, title)
values(6, 26, '6a');
insert into @children(id, connection, title)
values(7, 21, '1b');
insert into @children(id, connection, title)
values(8, 22, '2b');
insert into @children(id, connection, title)
values(9, 23, '3b');
insert into @children(id, connection, title)
values(10, 24, '4b');
insert into @children(id, connection, title)
values(11, 25, '5b');
insert into @children(id, connection, title)
values(12, 26, '6b');

select 1 as tag, null as parent,
 id as [p!1!id],
 title as [p!1!title],
 null as [c!2!id],
 null as [c!2!title]
from @parents p
union
 select 2 as tag, 1 as parent,
 p.id, 
 p.title, 
 c.id,
 c.title
from @parents p, @children c
where p.connection = c.connection
for xml explicit
```

and here is the strange result I am getting:

```
<p id="1" title="1" />
<p id="2" title="2" />
<p id="3" title="3" />
<p id="4" title="4" />
<p id="5" title="5" />
<p id="6" title="6">
  <c id="1" title="1a" />
  <c id="7" title="1b" />
  <c id="2" title="2a" />
  <c id="8" title="2b" />
  <c id="3" title="3a" />
  <c id="9" title="3b" />
  <c id="4" title="4a" />
  <c id="10" title="4b" />
  <c id="5" title="5a" />
  <c id="11" title="5b" />
  <c id="6" title="6a" />
  <c id="12" title="6b" />
</p>
```

OK - I think I need to be more specific, and include the "Sequence" portion of my problem as well as the original issue. Given the following data set:

```
declare @parents table(id int, connection int, title nvarchar(255), sequence int);
declare @children table(id int, connection int, title nvarchar(255), sequence int);

insert into @parents(id, connection, title, sequence)
values(1, 21, '1', 6), (2, 22, '2', 2), (3, 23, '3', 4), (4, 24, '4', 3), (5, 25, '5', 5), (6, 26, '6', 1);

insert into @children(id, connection, title, sequence)
values(1, 21, '1a', 2), (2, 22, '2a', 2), (3, 23, '3a', 2), (4, 24, '4a', 1), (5, 25, '5a', 2), (6, 26, '6a', 1), (7, 21, '1b', 1), (8, 22, '2b', 1), (9, 23, '3b', 1), (10, 24, '4b', 2), (11, 25, '5b', 1), (12, 26, '6b', 2);
```

How can I get the following result that has data like this:

```
<p id="6" title="6" sequence="1">
  <c id="6" title="6a" />
  <c id="12" title="6b" />
</p>
<p id="1" title="2" sequence="2">
 <c id="8" title="2b" sequence="1" />
 <c id="2" title="2a" sequence="2" />
</p>
```

with the

elements ordered by sequence and their child elements order by sequence within each?

Thanks for your help...I hope this more fully explains what I need, and why I am trying to use explicit mode.

Comment: What result would you like to get?

Comment: Also: are you aware that in SQL Server 2008, you can add multiple value tuples to a table like this:  `insert into @parents(id, connection, title) values(1, 21, '1'), (2, 22, '2'), (3, 23, '3') ......`

Comment: The result I want looks like this:
<p id="1" title="1">
  <c id="1" title="1a" />
  <c id="7" title="1b" />
</p>
<p id="2" title="2">
  <c id="2" title="2a" />
  <c id="8" title="2b" />
</p>
<p id="3" title="3">
  <c id="3" title="3a" />
  <c id="9" title="3b" />
</p>
<p id="4" title="4">
  <c id="4" title="4a" />
  <c id="10" title="4b" />
</p>
<p id="5" title="5">
  <c id="5" title="5a" />
  <c id="11" title="5b" />
</p>
<p id="6" title="6">
  <c id="6" title="6a" />
  <c id="12" title="6b" />
</p>

I will eventually want to ensure the order of the children thats why I am using explicit mode

Comment: Thanks for the tip about multiple value tuples...that is a handy thing!

Comment: @rogdawg: updated my answer to produce the output you're looking for - does that work for you??

Comment: Thanks for your follow-up. I updated my original question to more fully explain why I was attempting to use xml explicit. I have used xml for path quite alot, and I have never found a way to order the children in a nested object. So, I was attempting Explicit. But, since I was having problems with even the simplest case, I thought I would try to get a solution to that and then add the order-by-sequence layer to the problem.
Thanks again. I really do appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @rogdawg: just use an `order by sequence` both at the parent level, as well as the child level. Seems pretty easy.... try my yet-again updated answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SQL Server 2005 and up, forget about `FOR XML EXPLICIT` - use `FOR XML PATH` instead - it's much easier to use, more expressive, more intuitive.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    p.ID AS '@id',
    p.title AS '@title',
    p.sequence as '@sequence',
    (SELECT 
         c.ID AS '@id', 
         c.Title AS '@title',
         c.sequence as '@sequence'
     FROM @children c 
     WHERE p.connection = c.connection
     ORDER BY c.sequence
     FOR XML PATH('c'), TYPE
    )
FROM    
    @parents p
ORDER BY    
    p.sequence
FOR XML PATH('p')
```

Output will be this: (order by p.sequence on the outer scope, and c.sequence in the inner scope)

```
<p id="6" title="6" sequence="1">
  <c id="6" title="6a" sequence="1" />
  <c id="12" title="6b" sequence="2" />
</p>
<p id="2" title="2" sequence="2">
  <c id="8" title="2b" sequence="1" />
  <c id="2" title="2a" sequence="2" />
</p>
<p id="4" title="4" sequence="3">
  <c id="4" title="4a" sequence="1" />
  <c id="10" title="4b" sequence="2" />
</p>
<p id="3" title="3" sequence="4">
  <c id="9" title="3b" sequence="1" />
  <c id="3" title="3a" sequence="2" />
</p>
<p id="5" title="5" sequence="5">
  <c id="11" title="5b" sequence="1" />
  <c id="5" title="5a" sequence="2" />
</p>
<p id="1" title="1" sequence="6">
  <c id="7" title="1b" sequence="1" />
  <c id="1" title="1a" sequence="2" />
</p>
```

See the [MSDN documentation on what's new in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137%28SQL.90%29.aspx#forxml2k5_topic6) for more hints and tips how to use the `FOR XML PATH` to generate XML from your database contents...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can do this several ways but, I need to use Explicit mode because I need to ensure that the children are in a certain order (I did not include the "sequence" column in my example) and the only way to do that (that I am aware of) is using Explicit Mode. Does that sound right? Thanks.

Comment: @rogdawg: no way - you can specify an ORDER BY in this query and use FOR XML PATH. You might need to be a bit more specific for your question - but I'm 95% sure you can do this with FOR XML PATH much easier than with FOR XML EXPLICIT

Comment: I was using the "for xml path" while trying to use an inner join to connect the children to the parent, and that was giving me bizarre sorting results. I didn't think about using a sub query to connect the children to the parent. That is fantastic solution, and certainly more elegant than "for xml explicit".
Thanks very much for sticking with this until it was solved!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 
Given this data:

```
declare @parents table(id int, connection int, title nvarchar(255), sequence int);
declare @children table(id int, connection int, title nvarchar(255), sequence int);

insert into @parents(id, connection, title, sequence)
values(1, 21, '1', 6), (2, 22, '2', 2), (3, 23, '3', 4), (4, 24, '4', 3), (5, 25, '5', 5), (6, 26, '6', 1);

insert into @children(id, connection, title, sequence)
values(1, 21, '1a', 2), (2, 22, '2a', 2), (3, 23, '3a', 2), (4, 24, '4a', 1), (5, 25, '5a', 2), (6, 26, '6a', 1), (7, 21, '1b', 1), (8, 22, '2b', 1), (9, 23, '3b', 1), (10, 24, '4b', 2), (11, 25, '5b', 1), (12, 26, '6b', 2);
```

DO YOUR SELECT STATEMENT LIKE THIS:

```
select p.id [@id], p.title [@title], p.sequence [@sequence], 
    (select c.id [@id], c.title [@title], c.sequence [@sequence]
     from @children c
     where c.connection = p.connection
     order by c.sequence
     for xml path('child'), type)
from @parents p
for xml path('parent'), type
```